# How do ferrite beads work?

Tags: frequency, electronics

How do ferrite beads, those small cylinders found on cables, work? I understand that they are meant to filter out high frequency noise. I also understand what  a low-pass filter is and how an inductor can be used as a low pass filter.

I have a problem understanding the actual design of these. As far as I understand they just consist of a block of ferrite material wrapped around the cable!? How does this act as an inductor?

Comment: They are lossy at high frequencies. So, high frequency components of your signal are (partially) absorbed in the lossy material.

Comment: Try looking up info on "common mode chokes". Here's an example: http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/26to30.ashx